# Loopback-MongoDB : db.runCommand is not a function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, loopbackjs, loopback

I am using loopback.

I need to find all unique filed names from collection.

I have used below method to access mongodb.

```
Act.getUserFields = function (actId, parentActId, callbackFn) {
        this.app.dataSources.mongoConnector.connector.connect(function (errconnect, mdb) {
            if (errconnect) callbackFn(errconnect, {});
            else {
                console.log('mdb', mdb);
                if (mdb) {
                    var mr = mdb.runCommand({
                        "mapreduce": "User",
                        "map": function () {
                            for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
                        },
                        "reduce": function (key, stuff) { return null; },
                        "out": "User" + "_keys"
                    });

                    mdb[mr.result].distinct("_id").toArray(function (errFields, docFields) {
                        if (errFields) callbackFn(errFields, {});
                        else {
                            callbackFn(null, docFields);
                        }
                    });
                } else callbackFn("Db is not found", {});
            }
        });
    };
```

I am getting error after connecting. `TypeError: mdb.runCommand is not a function`

Can anyone tell me what am i missing here?

Comment: I guess `mdb` is the database reference, isn't it? To execute map-reduce query, use `mapReduce`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/index.html . I'd guess `db.collection('User').mapReduce(map, reduce, {"out": out})`, where `map`, `reduce` and `out` are accordingly bound variables.

Comment: I am new to this. Can you provide complete query from which i can get same result as i should get from my query.

Comment: Try `mdb.collection('User').mapReduce(...)`